# MySQL Interval Expiry from Creation Timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, intervals

I am working on a project where one "lights a virtual candle" and I want to create a cron job that selects all records from the database that are expiring in the next five days, possibly calculated from the databases "created_date" field which type is "Type: TIMESTAMP > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Process:
The candle duration = 30 days
Alert period = 5 days before the 30 days

This is what I have so far (I can do the rest, it is the query I am having problems with)

```
$query_rsQueryA = "SELECT * FROM $databaseName WHERE created_date + INTERVAL 5 DAY < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;";
$rsQueryA = mysql_query($query_rsQueryA) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsQueryA = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsQueryA);
$totalRows_rsQueryA = mysql_num_rows($rsQueryA);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please specify your problem with this query?

Comment: Yeha, sorry. It actually works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears what I have written above actually works, should have tried it first guys, sorry about that!

Comment: Err, wot do you mean: 'should have tried it first'? You actually did not try to test your own code before asking the question? rofl

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
datediff(now(),date_add(created_date,INTERVAL 25 day)) > 0
```

So basically its adding 25 day to the created_date and then finding the difference with the current date and if its greater than 0 meaning start sending alert

Comment: Works great, however it through up some other things with my code, so I have now added the expiry_date into the database and now need to do the same with them. Any ideas?

Comment: if you set the expire date in the DB that would be more easy just do as `datediff(now(),expiry_date) >=0` so it will find the diff from 0 i.e. expired today, yesterday etc.

Comment: A flat number did not work based on CREATED (2014-04-28 07:51:11) EXPIRY (2014-05-03 07:51:11)

But this did show up on the query:

$query_rsQueryA = "SELECT * FROM $databaseName WHERE datediff(now(),expiry_date) > -6";

Comment: Ah i see I am sorry you can do as `datediff(expiry_date,now()) >=0`

Comment: Thanks, but rather than today I need it to be 5 days BEFORE expiry :) - which is the best method?

Comment: Fantastic, just wanted clarification! :D

Comment: One more thing if you run a cron script for this which runs every day then `datediff(now(),expiry_date) > -6` will be always true. So probably the reverse is better